# How can I make this onclick="call_locker();" to work on my script?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've been trying to figure this out for a week now.

I can't figure it out how to implement this `onclick` locker to my script.
I'm lost can't figure it out.

This is the code for the `<head>`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">var lck = false;</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.cpagrip.com/script_include.php?id=63453"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">if(!lck){top.location = 'http://lokhlp.com/disable_AdBlock.php'; }</script><noscript>Please enable JavaScript to access this page.<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=http://lokhlp.com/enable_javascript.php" /></noscript>
```

This is the code to call the locker:

```
onclick="call_locker();"
```

How can I activate the locker on this?

```
var t2=setTimeout("document.getElementById('download').innerHTML='<a href=\"#\"> <div class=\"download-button\"> <p> Download </p> </div> </a>'",10700);
```

The `<div class="download-button">` doesn't have image.

Here's the code in the CSS:

```
.download-button {
    background-color:#3ab2de;
    padding:10px;
    position:relative;
    width:150px;
    height:40px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size:16px;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#fff;
    background-image: linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(100,170,30) 0%, rgb(129,212,51) 100%);
    box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px #7fd2f1, 0px 6px 0px #156785;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.download-button:active {
    top:7px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(100,170,30) 100%, rgb(129,212,51) 0%);
    box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px #7fd2f1, inset 0px -1px 0px #156785;
    color: #156785;
    text-shadow: 0px 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
    background: rgb(44,160,202);
}

.download-button::before {
    background-color:#072239;
    content:"";
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    padding-left:2px;
    padding-right:2px;
    padding-bottom:4px;
    left:-2px;
    top:5px;
    z-index:-1;
    border-radius: 6px;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 0px #fff;
}

.download-button:active::before {
    top:-2px;
}

.download-button p {
text-align:center;
margin-top:10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you want is this:

```
var t2=setTimeout(function() { document.getElementById('download').innerHTML='<a href=\"#\"> <div class=\"download-button\"> <p> Download </p> </div> </a>'; call_locker(); }, 10700);
```

Keep in mind though, this is a timeout and it's set to 10700, which is 10.7 seconds. Do you want `call_locker()` to be called immediately, or after 10.7 seconds?

Comment: It didn't worked! It gave much error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null
event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead.

Comment: The code is a download button. The download button will appear after 10.7 and when the button is pressed the call locker will activate

Comment: Do you have an element on your page with `id="download"`? You haven't  provided your HTML, so I can't see why this error is happening.